# how to trigger 2 write actions in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have basically 2 save actions to execute on my dataframe. The job is running fine. But when I see the the event timeline in Spark UI, I understand that first Action 1 completes, then Action 2 starts and completes.

Since these 2 actions are independent on each other, is there any way to execute them together. Below is my code.

```
processedDF.write.format("ORC").options(Map("path" ->
integrationFullPath)).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable(HIVE_SCHEMA + "."
+ hiveTableName + "_int")
errorDF.write.format("ORC").options(Map("path" ->
errorFullPath)).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable(HIVE_SCHEMA + "." +
hiveTableName + "_error")
```

I want to process both "processDF" and "errorDF" write simultaneously into HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

You can start these in different threads:

```
   new Thread() {
      override def run(): Unit = {
       processedDF.write.format("ORC").options(Map("path" ->
integrationFullPath)).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable(HIVE_SCHEMA + "."
+ hiveTableName + "_int")
      }
    }.start()



    new Thread() {
          override def run(): Unit = {
           errorDF.write.format("ORC").options(Map("path" ->
errorFullPath)).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable(HIVE_SCHEMA + "." +
hiveTableName + "_error")
          }
        }.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the scheduling documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application). Reproducing the relevant section verbatim:

> Inside a given Spark application (SparkContext instance), multiple parallel jobs can run simultaneously if they were submitted from separate threads.[...] By default, Spark’s scheduler runs jobs in FIFO fashion. Each job is divided into “stages” (e.g. map and reduce phases), and the first job gets priority on all available resources while its stages have tasks to launch, then the second job gets priority, etc.[...] Starting in Spark 0.8, it is also possible to configure fair sharing between jobs. Under fair sharing, Spark assigns tasks between jobs in a “round robin” fashion, so that all jobs get a roughly equal share of cluster resources. This means that short jobs submitted while a long job is running can start receiving resources right away and still get good response times, without waiting for the long job to finish.
>
> To enable the fair scheduler, simply set the spark.scheduler.mode property to FAIR when configuring a SparkContext:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(...).setAppName(...)
conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for a solution I did the same using Future

```
@volatile var terminated = false
    import scala.concurrent._
    import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    
    val f1= Future{processedDF.write.format("ORC").options(Map("path" ->
integrationFullPath)).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable(HIVE_SCHEMA + "."
+ hiveTableName + "_int")}

    val f2= Future{errorDF.write.format("ORC").options(Map("path" ->
errorFullPath)).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable(HIVE_SCHEMA + "." +
hiveTableName + "_error")}
    val aggregatedFuture = for{
      f1Result <- f1
      f2Result <- f2
    } yield (f1Result, f2Result)
    Thread.sleep(500) 
    terminated = true
    val res = Await.result(aggregatedFuture, Duration.Inf)
```